# `GLIBC_2.16' not found for an application

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, glibc

I am trying to develop an application for a Linux based custom device. My build environment(Ubuntu 16.04) uses GLIBC-2.23 and all of other applications use this version but new custom device uses an old version of GLIBC so I am getting

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /opt/myapp/lib/libcurl.so.4)
```

I cannot change my build environment and I cannot update also custom device GLIBC.

So, got stuck. 
Maybe I can link new glibc version just with my application explicity but I dont know how can I do that?

I tried following but stil same

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 --library-path /opt/myapp/lib/ <APP>
```

Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot change my build environment

You sure *can* do that, in several different ways, such as:

1. Install a virtual machine configured to use older GLIBC, compile the app inside of the VM
2. Configure a chroot environment, with older GLIBC and toolchain
3. Build a linux-to-older GLIBC cross-compiler.

> Maybe I can link new glibc version just with my application

That's possible, but more complicated. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).